# What are all the automorphisms of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

The field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$? is defined as $\{a+b\sqrt{2}: a, b \in \mathbb{Q}\}$.

Are there only two automorphisms, one mapping to $\{a+b\sqrt{2}\}$ and the other mapping to $\{a-b\sqrt{2}\}$?

Comment: Please include more details. And make the body self-contained. The title is not part of the question.

Comment: Why do you think that those are the only two? Why do you think that they might not be? In short, what have you tried?

Comment: @JohnHughes, I am not fishing for solutions, but I do not know what to try.

Comment: Here's a start for what you *might* have said. "I know that for any automorphism $f$, I have to have $f(a + b\sqrt{2}) = c + d \sqrt{2}$ for some $c$ and $d$, and that $f(pq) = f(p) f(q)$ because it's an automorphism. I tried thinking about $a$ and $b$ like a basis, so I'd write $f(1) = c + d \sqrt{2}$ and $f(\sqrt{2}) = e + f \sqrt(2)$, and then I can use linearity to find $f(a + b\sqrt{2})$ for any $a$ and $b$, but then I'm stuck..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

Consider that $\varphi:\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2)\to\Bbb Q(\sqrt2)$ is an automorphism. Then it fixes $1$ and thus also fixes each integer and rational numbers.

Once $\gamma:=\varphi(\sqrt2)$ is decided/found, we must have
$$\varphi(a+b\sqrt2)=a+b\gamma$$
for all $a,b\in\Bbb Q$ because $\varphi$ respects all field operations.

Finally, observe that, as $(\sqrt2)^2=2$, we must also have $\gamma^2=2$.