# Is this still the smallest subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ that contains $\sqrt{d}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know from a previous question that by construction a field $\mathbb{Q(\sqrt{d})}$ is the smallest subfield of that contains $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\sqrt{d}$. But it seems to be not true if $d$ is a perfect square, then the smallest subfield would actually be $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\sqrt{d}}$)?

Comment: No, if $d$ is a perfect square, $\sqrt d \in \mathbb Q$, so the smallest field is $\mathbb Q$ itself.

Answer (score 2):

If $K\le L$ are fields, $\alpha\in L$, then *by definition*
$K(\alpha)$ is the smallest field (subfield of $L$) that contains $K$ and $\alpha$.

Hence, if already $\alpha\in K$ (as in the case when $\alpha=\sqrt d$ and $d$ is a perfect square),  then $K(\alpha)=K$ by definition

Comment: Thank you, can you please help me with http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1421951/what-are-all-the-automorphisms-of-mathbbq-sqrt2?